# What is the origin of the phrase "Gag me with a spoon"?

Tags: etymology, phrases

How does a phrase such as "Gag me with a spoon" originate? I understand the sentiment as a real concept — gagging oneself with a spoon causes a choking sensation without actually constricting breathing. It's uncomfortable and disconcerting.

But, how did this become the go-to dismissive phrase of the 80s?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The phrase "gag me with a spoon" originates from [Valley girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valley_girl) speak, which is in turn an obnoxious form of Californian english. From the wiki article:

> Valley Girl (or Val, Val Gal) is a stereotype leveled at a socio-economic and ethnic class of American women who can be described as colloquial English-speaking, materialistic, self-centered, hedonistic, and often sexually promiscuous. Valspeak is also a form of this trait, based on an exaggerated version of '80s California English.

The phrase is used as an expression of disgust. A typical usage from the [online slang dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-of/gag-me-with-a-spoon)

> Oh my gosh, gag me with a spoon. That were the ugliest shoes I've ever seen!

The phrase also appears in Frank Zappa's song, [Valley girl](http://youtu.be/489pO9q8guA).

> .../Its like grody.../ Grody to the max/ Im sure/ Its like really nauseating/ Like barf out/ **Gag me with a spoon**/ Gross/ I am sure/ Totally...

---

As for the *how*, you could perhaps reason that the act of gagging yourself with a spoon is pretty disgusting and hence it makes sense. However, I'm not sure you should look for a reason/proper etymology for any of the valley girl-isms (*ummm*, *like*, *totally*, *so bitchin'*, *whatever*, etc.).

Comment: ...if there's any snippets of "Square Pegs" on youtube, they'd make a wonderful (?) example of Valley Girl speak.  Like, totally!

Answer (score 10):

The origins of the phrase is derived from the practice of forcing oneself to vomit, a typical trait of [bulimia nervosa](http://www.bulimia.com/topics/bulimia/). The sufferer will often use their own fingers or a long narrow instrument to induce vomiting; e.g. a spoon handle.

> [How to Identify Symptoms of Bulimia](http://www.ehow.com/how_4457474_identify-symptoms-bulimia.html)
>   Look for evidence of laxatives in your home. Many teens purge through
>   the help of laxative abuse. They also purge by sticking their fingers
>   or other objects down their throat. **Look for the presence of spoons** or
>   other objects that don't belong in a bathroom for signs of this.

*Borderline Personality Disorder*: *New Reasons for Hope*
 <sup>[By Francis Mark Mondimore, Patrick Kelly](http://books.google.it/books?id=Q1zkMHNnUr0C&pg=PT82&dq=bulimia%20gag%20spoon&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v3KEU7noDeT_4QSk_IGICg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=bulimia%20gag%20spoon&f=false)</sup>

> The hallmark of bulimia is binge eating, during which persons eat
>   enormous amounts of food, often high-calorie foods, over a period of
>   an hour or so [...]When a person who has bulimia cannot force another bite, she is overcome with disgust and shame at what she has done and seeks a way to rid herself of the calorie load. the vast majority of persons ... do this by forcing themselves to vomit. [...] Individuals with bulimia **usually stimulate their gag reflex by putting a finger or spoon down the throat** in the early stages of their disorder but often become adept at vomiting at will.

[image]

Despite the [Ngram's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gag%20me%20with%20a%20spoon&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,gag%20me%20with%20a%20spoon;,c0) chart's display which suggests the phrase predates the 80s, the earliest recorded usage of this [Valleyspeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valleyspeak) I could find were dated 1980 and 1981 respectively.

*Air Force Driver,* [Volumes 14-16](http://books.google.it/books?id=P6s5AQAAMAAJ&q=%22gag%20me%20with%20a%20spoon%22&dq=%22gag%20me%20with%20a%20spoon%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=73aEU9yRLamO4gTG14GYBA&redir_esc=y)

> Like barfme out; **gag me with a spoon**. “Oh migosh! I'm getting a used
>   four-wheel-drive. That's going to be like really, like a lot of money
>   - I'm freakin' out, I'm sure. But, I don't know; like it's going to be like so cool, you know. Like see my 4X4.

and *The William and Mary Review*, [Volumes 19-22](http://books.google.it/books?id=l-A1AAAAIAAJ&q=%22gag%20me%20with%20a%20spoon%22&dq=%22gag%20me%20with%20a%20spoon%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=73aEU9yRLamO4gTG14GYBA&redir_esc=y)

> "I love you," said Justin Oligarchy "**Gag me with a spoon**," said Eunice
>   Babel absently, looking again to Joseph Beaumont Darrow IV Two fire
>   trucks roared up to the Auditorium, their sirens wailing. "What's the
>   trouble here?"

A very well written piece charting and explaining the "rise and fall" of this expression, forever linked to the 80s, is in the article *Gag Me With a Spoon: “Val-Speak” Takes Over SoCal* by Jennifer Ouellette

> Frank Zappa’s quirky Top 40 hit from 1982, “Valley Girl,” doesn’t get
>   much radio airplay these days, even on the “nostalgia” stations, but
>   it captured the birth of a linguistic phenomenon in the running
>   commentary provided by his daughter, Moon Unit — “val-speak,” a
>   strange dialect spoken by the female denizens of the San Fernando
>   valley area in Southern California characterized by ending sentences
>   with a slight rise in pitch, as if asking a question, now known as
>   “uptalk.” And it might have stayed in the Valley, too, if it weren’t
>   for that meddling musician and his daughter, who broadcast it to the
>   masses. **Soon everyone was walking around declaring their school
>   lunches were “grody to the max,” I mean, “gag me with a spoon,”** every
>   uptalking utterance punctuated by frequent insertions of “like” and
>   “totally.”

Source: [Scientific American.com](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/cocktail-party-physics/2013/12/08/gag-me-with-a-spoon-val-speak-takes-over-socal/)

Comment: Great comment. I never made this connection and the Ngram plot was great.